# How do i update the column in PowerApp When i have change it in sharepointlist?

Tags: powerapps, sharepoint-list

I changed one column from online text to 5 choises
PowerApp dont auto update from the source. But i can't see
A way to just reload the column from sharepointlist.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image solution for this problem =)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Best to remove that field in the form and then re-add it. It will pull in then all the updated meta data from SharePoint.

Comment: Yes i found this way was the only way i could solve it♥